# Nodej.js : Static file caching not working due unnecessary query parameter

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

My Node.js code to cache the static files as follows :

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public"),
    { maxAge: (process.env.NODE_ENV === "local") ? 0 : 31557600000 }));
```

The public folder contains all the static files for my server.

The html code (I am using EJS )  which calls the static file is :

```
<script src="/assets/js/slick.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/main.js"></script>
<!--for form validation -->
<script src="/assets/js/parsley.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/wheelzoom.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/alertify.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/alertify.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/validator.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/jquery.bootstrap.wizard.min.js"></script>
```

But when I visit the page and checked the network tab on chrome, I see that due to query parameter added to the static file get calls, browser is not loading the file from cache, instead it requests the server.

[image]

Why a `__SbCache` is being added to those static files ? Due this issue, static file caching is not working properly.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, which is only occurs in chrome.

I found that's because of a chrome extension:**Postman Interceptor 0.2.24**

When I disable it, the problem disappear.

Comment: Yup! I had a similar issue. I was using session box extension. When I not used, everything worked fine.